# SalesForce & OpenAM integration issue

Tags: integration, salesforce, openam

I am doing  integration of SalesForce and OpenSSO with SAML. I have implemented steps mentioned on site

- http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_SAML_on_Force.com

There are two important use cases for SAML

1. Identity Provider Initiated Login, where a user starts directly at their identity provider, logs in, and is then redirected to a landing page at the service provider;
   ----This case working fine
2. Service Provider Initiated Login, where a user starts by clicking a link to the the service provider (e.g. a bookmark, mailed link, etc.) and temporarily redirected to the identity provider for authentication, then returned to the link they initially requested.

I am trying to implement 2nd Scenario :I am performing following steps

1. created my domain  in SalesForce and deployed for Users
2. Added Identity Provider in Single Sign-On Settings
3. When I access My Domain URL. It redirect me to Identity provider login page.
4. After login to IDP it won’t redirect back to SalesForce page. It shows IDP success page.

How should I redirect back to SalesForce success page?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce's SP initiated SAML implementation is basically a hack - You need to first fire off an IDP initiated SAML response which contains an attribute called ssoStartPage. this points to your IDP login page. Once salesforce has seen this attribute it remembers it and uses it for future (SP initiated) requests. [This post](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Security/SSO-Federated-Authentication-Help-needed/m-p/182941/highlight/true#M145) should hopefully help you (see point 3 at the bottom)